# Objective C compiling with clang on Linux Foundation/Foundation.h linking: file not found

Tags: objective-c, compilation, clang, gnustep

I'm trying to compile a program in Objective C on Ubuntu, I have installed GNUstep, set all the `GNUSTEP_*` environment variables, and installed clang, because I read that gcc can't compile Objective-C code with blocks (Objective-C 'anonymous' functions, just to be clear: `^ { }`).

What I get when I run this command:
`clang hello.m -o hello`

Is:

```
hello.m:1:9: fatal error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
```

I tried this also:
`clang -L '/usr/include/GNUstep/Foundation/Foundation.h' hello.m -o hello`

Where `/usr/include/...` is the path to the Foundation.h file on my system; but I still get the same result.

How can I link those header files automatically and compile Objective-C?

Thanks!

Comment: In general, it's much easier to build with a GNUmakefile than to try to supply all the arguments yourself. See http://www.gnustep.it/nicola/Tutorials/WritingMakefiles/.

Comment: Also, `-L` is used to specify a *library* *directory*, i.e. the location of a .so or .dylib file whose name you also supplied using `-l`. Perhaps you were thinking of `-I/usr/include/GNUstep`; that would tell it where the root directory for *include* files is. In no case would you supply the full path to the actual library or header file (well, it is possible to supply a path to library files, but it's rarely done).

Comment: Apparently you are using the gcc objc runtime. Which IIRC does not support block. You should better use the libobjc2

Comment: All right, I checked the repositories and I have libojc4 installed, but I can't find libobjc2, could this be a problem?

Comment: libobjc2 is the lib coming from gnustep: https://github.com/gnustep/gnustep-libobjc2

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnustep-config:

```
clang `gnustep-config --objc-flags` `gnustep-config --objc-libs` hello.m -o hello
```

Comment: Thanks, I have moved something. Now I don't get the Foundation/Foundation.h error but this:

Comment: Sorry, I left this:

/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/Foundation/Foundation.h:31:9: fatal error: 
      'objc/objc.h' file not found

-- As I can suppose clang doesn't find the objc/objc.h file, am I right?

Apparently the file is located in this path (I used the locate objc/objc.h command):

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/include/objc/objc.h

So how can I bind it to the path where clang is gonna look when I launch it?

Comment: You need the objc runtime. You should better use the GNUstep Makefile.

Comment: Yes with the GNUstep Makefile all goes great except that I cannot compile code with Blocks, and I need them, so I came up with clang which compiles blocks, but I still get this errors.

How can I download the objc runtime, is it available on the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: When you build GNUStep you have to specify the the default compiler is clang. When building GNUstep make you should have configure it with `./configure  CC=clang CXX=clang++`. Rebuild and install GNUStep make and you will have it.